# How to delete many hashes

Tags: redis

I have many redis hashes like:

```
offer:1:20120909
offer:1:20120908
offer:1:20120909
offer:1:20120906
...
```

How can I remove the keys, without knowing the whole list of them?

I use [phpredis](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis).

Comment: You cannot do that in an efficient way with Redis.

Comment: One solution is to create a set to keep track of the keys then use the delete command with the result from this set.